# What is required to limit the amount of draw calls in Unity?

Tags: drawing, unity

I would like to limit the amount draw calls to approximate performance. Is there a nominal amount to aim for when working with high performance gaming?

From my understanding to render an object that contains exceptional amount of vertices, this would require a lot of draw calls. Though, without doing dynamic draw calls, is there another way to limit the amount of draw calls?

Per example, if the number draw calls is to be 60 for 60 frames per second; this rate is completely arbitrary, am just looking for a basic explanation on how to control this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a bit of [information](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/14578/whats-the-best-way-to-reduce-draw-calls.html) about this:

- Static/dynamic batching: basically combining objects into one super-object
- Atlas textures: combining textures into one large texture than only uses one material
- Switch to a deferred renderer if you are using many lights

> From my understanding to render an object that contains exceptional amount of vertices, this would require a lot of draw calls.

The vertex amount doesn't directly determine the number of draw calls. There also isn't really a guide on how many draw calls is too much. The best thing to do is to profile your application and see where your performance problems come from.